# What's the best way to offer javascript embed that won't slow a page down?

Tags: javascript, embed

I have a chunk of javascript that users can copy and paste to put on their sites.

I'm currently using the following code (ala [WEDJE](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2007/06/widget-deployment-with-wedje)) that allows the rest of the page to load even if my script is slow or not responding.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var number = "987654321";
  var key = "123abc";

  (function(){
    document.write('<div id="ttp"></div>');
    s=document.createElement('script');
    s.type="text/javascript";
    s.src="http://example.com/javascripts/embed.js?" + Math.random(); 
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('ttp').appendChild(s);",1);
  })()
</script>
```

But that method is a few years old and so I wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way of doing the same thing that others have come up with.

Comment: OT (sorry!) but I think you should declare your `s` variable as `var s = document.createElement('script');`. Otherwise you will write it in the global object despite that you run your stuff in a nice anonymous function. (If one of your "outer" variables would be `s`, it would be wrecked when you assign the script element to it inside your function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is still i pretty common way to do it when you need to load a file "on demand" and in similar situations.
I also think I would append it as the last child to `body` though, instead of writing a new element to the DOM for the purposes of appending the script element.

Answer (score 0):

1) Save the file to your source directory so loading is not dependent on web connection

2) Load the script at the bottom of the page in regular script import fashion...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language=JavaScript src="/scripts/ext.utils.prototype.js"></script>
```

OR:

3)Check out http://labjs.com/ - though be warned you may have dependency issues